# Comparing nested lists within a parent list structure for values in specific indices in java

Tags: java, list, collections, iteration, nested-lists

Given a list of lists in the following format:

List < List < String, String, BigInteger, String, String, String, String, String, String > > rows

what would be the best way to iterate through each list searching for duplicate values for [1] (string for employee ID) and [2] (big integer for account ID) indices that match any other row's values for [1] and [2] in a list

so that if there are rows with duplicates of both account id's and employee id's an action can be done?

Comment: how the `List < String, String, BigInteger, String, String, String, String, String, String >` is really constructed? Did you created a new class to take care of `< String, String, BigInteger, String, String, String, String, String, String >`

Comment: yeah, it's a list of list's. Each list is a particular record. I'm trying to figure out the best way to check for entries where the employeeID and accountID are the same to handle batch processing for duplicate actions where these are the same. 

It seems however there is a groovy class of itself to handle pulling the related data directly from the database. I guess it would be perhaps good to create a list of those objects directly? 

@lbald

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing I got the meaning of the structure as follows:

`List< Row >`, where `Row` is the class you created to manage `List<String, String, BigInteger, String, String, String, String, String, String>`.

In this case you could override the method `equals()` in this class to match your "duplicated" values.

```
class Row {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Row) {
            return account.equals(((Row)o).getAccount())
                && employee.equals((Row)o).getEmployee());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your main list, you can apply one of the algorithms to find duplications. As in [https://crunchify.com/java-how-to-find-duplicate-elements-from-list/]. One example could be:

```
void processDuplicates (List<Row> list) {
    Set<Row> already = new HashSet<>();
    for (Row row : list) {
        if (already.contains(row)) {
            // row is duplicated
            // do something
        } else {
            already.add(row);
        }
    }
}
```